# Scintillation Crystals for Radiation detection

Tags: radiation, crystals, particle-detectors

As I understand it, scintillation crystals work by emitting a light pulse when they are hit by a high energy particle. But I'm struggling to find a good explanation of what is causing the light pulse

The two ways this would work that I can think of is that the light generated by:

- Changing the structure of the crystal, effectively 'degrading' it with more contact and the pulse results from dropping the energy level of the structure at the point of contact.
- The light results from lowering the energy of the incoming high-energy particle and the structure remains essentially unchanged.
- Or is there something else going on here?

For the practical application of this, if I were to use a scintillation crystal for a radiation detector would the crystals be a consumable that has to be replaced after a certain period/amount of radiation interaction or are they effectively infinite life components, limited by the hardware used to detect the light and not the crystals themselves.

Comment: Or the light results from states (often intentional impurities) excited by the gamma (usually through creation of a high energy electron that then loses energy through exciting other electrons) decaying back to a ground state. And, yes, they suffer radiation damage with a common solution being to thermally anneal the material.

Comment: @Jon Custer, sounds like that could be an answer!

Comment: @KFGauss - there are a multitude of near duplicates that I’m a bit busy to sort through and find the most appropriate one right now.

Comment: @Diesel - after reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scintillator, what part(s) are unclear?